# (verb)ing and (verb)ing with "show"

Tags: verbs, tenses

This is easiest to explain with examples:

**Examples**

- 1a: Shouting and cursing **shows** that you are rude.
- 1b: Shouting and cursing **show** that you are rude.
- 2a: Hitting the target and splitting the arrow **shows** that he is an
  accomplished archer.
- 2b: Hitting the target and splitting the arrow **show** that he is an
  accomplished archer.

In cases like this, is "show" or "shows" correct?? If they are both correct, is there any difference in the meaning conveyed? Are there times where one or the other would be more appropriate or effective?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you consider the two verbs as part of a single action, or as two different actions.

For 2, you should use 2a, because *"hitting the target and splitting the arrow"* would be considered a single action.

If you're talking about two different actions, you need to use *are*. For example, you would use *are* in *"passing and dribbling are two essential skills for soccer."*

And for 1, you could plausibly consider *shouting and cursing* as a single action, or as two different actions, so both *shows* and *show* work there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical difference, although the semantic difference is slight:

1a: If you shout and curse, you are rude.
1b: If you shout, you are rude. If you curse, you are rude.

And similarly for 2a and 2b.